# How to do One Hot Encoding for Linear Regression in Spark with Python?

Tags: python, encoding, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have this code which I had written for `Random Forest regression` encoding. But `Random Forest regression` does not require `One Hot Encoding` after `indexer`. Now I want to try the `Linear Regression` which requires `One Hot Encoding`. I went through the Sparks [One Hot Encoder](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) documentation but couldn't get how to incorporate that in my current code. How can I add the `One Hot Encoding` step in my current code?

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder

label_col = "x4"

# converting RDD to dataframe
train_data_df = train_data.toDF(("x0","x1","x2","x3","x4"))

# Indexers encode strings with doubles
string_indexers = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="idx_{0}".format(x))
   for x in train_data_df.columns if x != label_col
]

# Assembles multiple columns into a single vector
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["idx_{0}".format(x) for x in train_data_df.columns if x != label_col],
    outputCol="features"
)


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + [assembler])
model = pipeline.fit(train_data_df)
indexed = model.transform(train_data_df)

label_points = (indexed
.select(col(label_col).cast("double").alias("label"), col("features"))
.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel


###### FOR TEST DATA ######
label_col_test = "x4"

# converting RDD to dataframe
test_data_df = test_data.toDF(("x0","x1","x2","x3","x4"))

# Indexers encode strings with doubles
string_indexers_test = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="idx_{0}".format(x))
   for x in testData_df_1.columns if x != label_col_test
]

# encoders
encoders_test = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol="idx_{0}".format(x), outputCol="enc_{0}".format(x))
   for x in testData_df_1.columns if x != label_col_test
]

# Assembles multiple columns into a single vector
assembler_test = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["idx_{0}".format(x) for x in testData_df_1.columns if x != label_col_test],
    outputCol="features"
)


pipeline_test = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers_test + encoders_test + [assembler_test])
model_test = pipeline_test.fit(test_data_df)
indexed_test = model_test.transform(test_data_df)

label_points_test = (indexed_test
    .select(col(label_col_test).cast("float").alias("label"), col("features"))
    .map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))

# Build the model
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(label_points)

valuesAndPreds = label_points_test.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))

MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v, p): (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))
```

Comment: Can you please tell me which machine learning models in PySpark require One hot encoding and which ones do not? I am unable to figure out

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add it as a step between indexing and assembling:

```
encoders = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol="idx_{0}".format(x), outputCol="enc_{0}".format(x))
   for x in train_data_df.columns if x != label_col
]

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[
        "enc_{0}".format(x) for x in train_data_df.columns if x != label_col
    ],
    outputCol="features"
)


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + encoders + [assembler])
```

Comment: When I run Linear regression in Spark I get `MSE` as `inf`. Somethings wrong that I have in my code. I have posted the rest of my code in update section above.

Comment: This problem has been covered more than once on SO. If you don't tune your model is something you can expect.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to some of such posts that deal with tuning the model in Spark?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32646080/1560062, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33844399/1560062, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28232132/1560062

Comment: I added `iterations = 150` and `intercept = true` to the model definition but still get the `inf` as `MSE`

Comment: @JasonDonnald tuning the model is not an easy task. Did you try a grid search over your hyper-parameters?

Comment: @eliasah how do we do a grid search over hyper-parameters?

Comment: A naive approach is iterating over a list of entries for the number of iterations, applying a model and evaluating to preserve the number of iteration for the best model. You can also apply CV inside. You can apply this over all the parameter (hyper-parameters) of the model. This is called a grid search.

Comment: I advice you to read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) about Grid Search with scikit.learn which is theoretically similar.

Comment: Just one more doubt. In my code above(the one above update section), I have all the features column as categorical. Suppose there are certain feature columns that are not categorical but are numeric (in string format which will require a cast to double). How can I modify my `indexer` and `assembler` step to exclude those columns from getting encoded and then form the labeled point which has both the categorical and non categorical features?